# A tree with exactly two leaves is a path

Tags: graph-theory

I need to prove that

> if $A$ is tree with only two leaves then $A$ is a path.

I don't know if this is ok, can you help me?

Let $A$ be a tree with exactly 2 leaves.
Let $u$ and $v$ $\in V(A)$ be the leaves.
If $A$ is not a path, it means that exists $v_i\in V(A)$ which $d(v_i)\geq 3$ (degree) and a vertex $w\in V(A)$ where the edge $(v_i,w) \in E(A)$.

If $d(w)=1$ then $w$ is a leaf. That's a contradiction because $A$ only has two leaves.

If $d(w)\geq 2$ then exists a vertex $y\in V(A)$ and $d(y) = 1$ so that exists a $wy-path$, then $y$ is a leaf and that's a contradiction.

Comment: Look at the letter $\lambda$ and regard it as a tree; its root at the top has one child, which then has two children that are leaves. That tree has exactly two leaves, but is not a path. Perhaps you need to tell us your definition of "tree".

Comment: A tree is a connected acyclic graph

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Denote by $e$ the number of edges, by $v$ the number of vertices, and by $v_i\geq0$ the number of vertices of degree $i$ in your tree $A$. Then
$$\sum_{i\geq 1} i v_i=2e=2(v-1)=2\sum_{i\geq 1} v_i-2\ ,$$
and therefore
$$\sum_{i\geq3} (i-2) v_i=v_1-2=0\ .$$
It follows that $v_i=0$ for all $i\geq3$. Therefore $A$ contains, apart from its two leaves, only vertices of degree $2$. These are the inner vertices on the path $\gamma$ connecting the two leaves. If there were any more vertices they could not be connected to the vertices on $\gamma$, because these are already booked out.

Comment: I believe this contains a hidden assumption: consider a root of degree 1; its sole child has degree two, and the two children of that child are leaves. This is a 2-leaf tree that is not an arc. Of course, if "tree" means "binary tree", so that every node has 0 or two children, then the proof is correct. But that doesn't seem to have been in the original problem statement.

Comment: @JohnHughes: Here a *tree* is a connected graph without cycles,  not a data structure.

Comment: Ah...so in my example, the "root" would also be a leaf. Good enough!

Answer (score 3):

I think that you may have the right general idea, but so many details are missing that I can’t be sure. For instance, you’ve said nothing that would rule out the possibility that $y=u$ or $y=v$.

Try this. Since $A$ is a tree, there is a (unique) simple path $P$ from $u$ to $v$. Let the vertices of $P$ be $u=v_0,v_1,\ldots,v_n=v$ in order from $u$ to $v$. If $P$ is all of $A$, you’re done, so suppose that there is a vertex $w$ not on $P$. Then there is a simple path $Q$ from $w$ to $u$.

- Show that there must be a vertex $v_k$ lying on both $P$ and $Q$.

Let $m$ be maximal such that $x_m$ is on both $P$ and $Q$.

- Show that there is an edge $e=\{v_m,x\}$ incident at $v_m$ that is on $Q$ but not on $P$.

Remove the edge $e$; this breaks the tree $A$ into two components, one containing $P$ and the other containing the vertex $x$. Let $C$ be the component containing $x$. $C$ is a tree, and $x$ is a leaf of $C$. Every tree has at least two leaves, so let $y$ be another leaf of $C$.

- Show that $y$ is a leaf of $A$, contradicting the hypothesis that $A$ has only two leaves.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help, can you give a better idea how to prove that exits a the vertex $v_k$ on $P$ and $Q$? I'm trying but I'm going nowhere

Comment: @Daniela: The only edge leaving $u$ is the one to $v_1$, so that edge must be part of $Q$, and therefore $v_1$ is on both paths. Start at $u$ and travel along $P$ towards $v$; $v$ is not on $Q$ (why?), so there must be a last vertex $v_m$ that *is* on $Q$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $A$ is a tree, there is a (unique) simple path $P$ from $u$ to $v$.
We claim that all the vertices in the tree (except $u$ and $v$) are of degree 2. Hence, the tree has no vertices that are not in $P$ (if was some other vertex, it would has a path to $P$ and it would increase the degree of some vertex in $P$ to more the 2).
Proof. Let $S$ - `Prufer sequence`. $S$ has $n-2$ elements. All vertices that are not in $S$ are leaves. We have only 2 leaves, so $S$ contains all other ($n-2$) elements. So every vertex appear exactly one time in $S$. And that means that every vertex has 2 degree.